# How to make eclipse neon show git branch in package view?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I just [adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Sometimes eclipse shows the branch in the package view like: `foo [foo master]`.

My eclipse project is a gradle/java project that was created before doing a: `git init` and does not show the branch in the package view.

Also, nothing is shown in the git repositories view.

How do I get eclipse to show me the branch in the package view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your imported project into Eclipse workspace is a git repo, you can [Share your project with Git](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Create_Repository)

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/ae/Egit-0.9-getstarted-share.png]

If without creating a new repo, the act of selecting `File > Team > Share Project` and then `Git` should be enough for Eclipse to reconsider how it display your project in the Package Explorer (ie with git information on it)

---

If this does not work, the alternate approach would be to:

- switch to a new workspace
- import the project there,
- try and share it

(which the [OP Ray Tayek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51292/ray-tayek) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841992/how-to-make-eclipse-neon-show-git-branch-in-package-view/38844031?noredirect=1#comment65176549_38844031) having done successfully)

Comment: i see a different gui widget with: "configure git repo ..."  with: "use or create repo in parent folder of project.

Comment: @RayTayek That could mean you don't have a .git at the root folder of your project, meaning it is not yet a git repo.

Comment: @RayTayek or you have a .git folder, but not commit yet (nothing was never added). In both cases, you can check that with a git status. git add + git commit on command line is a good start, then you can switch back to Eclipse and try and the "Share Project" I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i created the project as a gradle project in eclipse. i have done two commits and push origin masters

Comment: @ray as a test, try with a new workspace, and import the project there, then try and share it.

Comment: good idea, i imported it as an existing project and it now shows:  foo [foo master]. add an answer and i'll mark it correct. thanks

Comment: @RayTayek I have edited the current answer to include this alternative.

Comment: The portion after `...the act of selecting...` worked for me. Upvote!

Answer (score 18):

The share option, as suggested by the previous answer, didn't work for me. However, Eclipse `Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations > check Git` did work. This made current brench visible in package view.

Comment: i must have had that turned on (it is now).

Comment: Everything git related was enabled for me, but after update Eclipse stopped displaying branch  names. Used  this menu section to enable/disable/enable and it started working again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My Eclipse Photon instance showed git decorations for some projects in the workspace and did not show the decorations for other projects in the same workspace.

It turned out that the projects without decorations were shallow copies (`git clone --depth 1 <...>`).

I resolved [the issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538549) by fetching some previous commits (`git fetch --depth 2`).